# limit of the function in case of non constant power

Tags: limits

Take the limit of $((x-2)/(x+2))^x$ as $x$ tends to infinity.

How can I simplify the expression in order to get something which I can calculate uisng useful limits?

Answer (score 4):

$$
\left(\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right)^x = \underbrace{\left( 1 - \frac 4 {x+2}\right)^{x+2}}_{\longrightarrow \, e^{-4}} \cdot \underbrace{\left( 1 - \frac 4 {x+2}\right)^{-2}}_{\longrightarrow\, 1}
$$

(If you don't know the result that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left( 1 + \dfrac a x \right)^x = e^a$, then start by learning that.)

Comment: thanks a lot Michael Hardy